# "can't escape _io.BufferedRandom to binary" when trying to insert image to BYTEA column

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2, bottle

So I'm trying to upload an image through bottle, and insert it into postgres `BYTEA` column with psycopg2, but I'm running into this error:

```
TypeError: can't escape _io.BufferedRandom to binary
```

From the `cursor.excute()` line that would insert the data.

Here's my code:

```
@route('/images', method='POST')
def upload_image():
    upload = request.files.get('image')
    img = Image.open(upload.file)  # Pillow
    binary = psycopg2.Binary(upload.file)
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    id = cursor.execute(
        '''
        INSERT INTO image (filename, data, width, height)
        VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)
        RETURNING id
        ''',
        (upload.filename, binary, img.width, img.height)
    )
    return id
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm wondering whether the problem is that `psycopg2.Binary` expects a string but is receiving a file-like object.  Have you tried something along these lines?

```
binary = psycopg2.Binary(upload.file.read())
```

Note: You may need to seek to the beginning of the file first, since (I'm guessing) the `Image.open` call on the previous line will consume all the bytes in `upload.file`.

Comment: Sorry forgot to come back and accept this, it worked nice with `file.seek(0)` :)